# Reading data from a webview in adroid and storing the data in kotlin array

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, android-webview

I am trying to create an app that takes user selections from some HTML drop downs (select tags) and stores them in the android app. I am trying to do this so I can create a autofill of sorts where users can decide what prefilled form they want to start with to save time and mitigate mistakes.

In the app I have a webview. The webview loads a webpage external to my device. I am struggling to find a way to read data from the webview. I want to be able to read and store user inputs from the webview in an array in kotlin.

I want to be able to run these java script commands but some how send the results to kotlin:

```
var v=document.getElementsByName("dropDownOne");

var ddO= v[0].value;



var f = document.getElementsByName("dropDownTwo");

var ddT= f[0].value;
```

I ran this in the chrome console and it provides me the data I need, I just need to figure out how to send this data to android.

I have tried using AndroidJSInterface but I am not able to get my head around it.

Here is my kotlin main activity class:

```
    object AndroidJSInterface {

        @JavascriptInterface
        fun onClicked() {
            Log.d("HelpButton", "Help button clicked")
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val view = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView) as WebView
        val webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                loadJs(view)
            }
        }


        val webView = WebView(this)
        webView.webViewClient = webViewClient

        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(AndroidJSInterface, "Android")

        setContentView(webView)
        webView.loadUrl(url)

        //ensures webview is embedded and no browser with address bar can be opened
        //view.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient())
        //view.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        //view.loadUrl(url)

    }

    private fun loadJs(webView: WebView) {
        webView.loadUrl(
            """javascript:(function f() {
                var v=document.getElementsByName("dropDownOne");
                var ddO= v[0].value;
                
                var f = document.getElementsByName("dropDownTwo");
                var ddT= f[0].value;    
                
                alert(ddO+ " > " + ddT);
                })()"""
        )
    }
```